# What does the diode do in this LSO (Low side output driver)?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis

I have a GCM196 with and I am trying to Ground a signal using a Low Side Output. There are pins with and without a diode. What does the diode do in this circuit?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your load is inductive (even a little bit), the back emf created by that inductance will splash a big impulse of voltage onto the MOSFET drain when the MOSFET de-activates. The diode will "catch" that impulse and suppress it back to the top of the load (also connected to the same supply). It's a pretty normal thing to see.

So, basically, it protects the MOSFET.

Comment: Will the diode be problematic if the load is a higher voltage than the supply (24V load, 12V supply)? In that case is the non-diode option better?

Comment: @cs_eng_516 if the load voltage is higher than the source it's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a clamp diode. It clamps the reverse voltage across the load to one diode drop Vf and clamps the MOSFET source to no higher than Vbatt+Vf.

In this case the cause of such a reverse voltage is inductive flyback in the load. But you can use a diode clamp to clamp other voltages to whatever supply rail it is connected to as well.

Answer (score 0):

The diode is a fly-back diode.  If the load is inductive, simply turning off the ground to it will cause the inductive load to attempt to continue to drive current (since inductors do not like to change their amperage quickly).  This will cause a voltage spike to come back at the driver from the load.

This pulse can be destructive, such as tens or hundreds of volts, and may easily exceed the Vds limits of the transistor, thereby possibly destroying it.  The diode therefore protects the transistor from those pulses.

Answer (score 0):

The diode protects the FET when driving inductive loads.

Current in inductor cannot be stopped immedately as the collapsing magnetic field will keep pushing current into the FET drain, and there is no path for it to flow when FET is off, so the induced voltage will be extremely high and can destroy the FET.

Basically the diode just clamps the voltage and diverts current into the battery supply pin.

Answer (score 0):

When the load stores energy (inductive) , the diode continues the current as the voltage is clamped just at the diode drop @ that instant current above the supply.

This diode clamp -only tends to be slower than a higher voltage clamp or zener & diode clamp but depends on the application.

The RF cap also reduces the slew rate of the Back EMF transient and amplitude but without the diode would resonate with a slightly smaller transient depending on the L/C ratio.